# js positioning moving to top corner

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been searching around for the answer and everything seems to lead that this code would work. Any ideas why its not?

```
$('.entertext').click(function(){

    $('.entertext').animate({opacity:0});
        //$('.move').animate({top:200, left:350});
        //$('.move').animate({top:0, left:0});

    $('.move').animate({"left": "-=350px", "top": "-=200px"});
        if ($('.move').left > 50) {
            $('.homepage').animate({opacity:1.0});
        }
    //$(this).animate({left:100});

});
```

Comment: What's the real question ? What do you want to do exactly ?

Comment: What I want exactly, is to make it say "when .move reaches the edge of the container, .homepage will fade in." or "when .move is offset a certain amount, .homepage will fade in."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `$('.move').left`

by `$('.move').offset().left`

Or `$('.move').css('left')` depending on your need.

Comment: or $('.move').position().left

Comment: Yes. But as in fact I really don't know what wants OP, I won't elaborate too much...

Comment: That works, thanks. I meant to ask how to make so that this will work:

Comment: I actually meant to ask how make it so if it reaches the corner of the container div, not if it's greater than 50.